# Is Ghost a good solution for a full website or is just blogging software?

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm building a new site and I'm wondering if [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) is a good solution since I need a website and a blog. Is Ghost just blogging software? Am I going to have to hack to pieces to get it to create pages separate from the blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghost is currently a blogging platform and a blogging platform only.

In the future they might go down the path to make it more of a fully-featured CMS, like Wordpress did, but I would not currently recommend using it in any other way than as a blog.

Sure, it's probably possible to do a full-fledged website in Ghost but it would without a doubt be a struggle and I would not recommend it.

I can see why your asking though, Ghost seems to have a lot of potential in its core values, not just as an blogging platform. :)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Fabian, Since I've never used Ghost that's exactly what I needed to know.